# Code generation or Annotation Processor for simple JPA fieldname constants

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, code-generation, annotation-processing

Currently we use [hibernate-jpamodelgen](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) to generate metadata about our entities.
Because the objects ("the objects" being implementations of javax.persistence.metamodel.Attribute) representing the entity-fields are only populated at runtime and are thus not constants, there are a couple of drawbacks:

- It is not possible to use them like simple String constants for jpa annotations like @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foobar")
- You have to find a workaround if those objects are used in a context that has not loaded an EntityManagerFactory - e.g. a unit test

The question is: Is there a simpler tool than hibernate-jpamodelgen that generates only (or as part of it) the entity fields' names as public static final Strings?

**EDIT:**

I created my own solution by forking hibernate-jpamodelgen and - in an admittedly not-so-elegant way - generating the required classes alongside the normal Metamodel classes.
If you are interested, please check out my fork on github: [Forked hibernate-jpamodelgen on github](https://github.com/LorenzSchumann/hibernate-orm/commit/b37b68c1c036e0a3b7f19d56261c2a0832368d0d)

Comment: JPA supports string based expressions (`javax.​persistence.​criteria.Expression<T>`) and paths (`javax.​persistence.​criteria.Path<X>`) to navigate through an entity. Drop the JPA static meta model, if it is unsuitable to your environment.

Comment: @Tiny I did not mean to be impolite by not responding to your comment. I just did not understand how that answers my question in any way. Again: Can i have @OneToMany(mappedBy = GeneretedClass.generatedField)? I just don't want to use error prone, hardcoded Strings here.